# Does cocoa butter help remedy chapped lips?

Tags: medical-science

Some people recommend cocoa butter be applied to chapped lips.

For example, [Natures Natural Healing](http://naturesnaturalhealing.com/ChappedLips.shtml):

> Treat chapped lips using cocoa butter - Applying a small amount of cocoa butter onto your chapped lips every couple of hours will help keep them moist. It is important to keep your lips moist so you don't get chapped lips.

Is there any study supporting the claim?

Comment: I always thought applying any fat to your lips would help keep them moist.

Comment: @Flimzy: not just fat, as oils such as petroleum jelly or paraffin wax are often used.